# NextJS / ReactJS - useEffect called before onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io, next.js

I have the following button in Next:

```html
<Button minWidth={'140px'} onClick={() => exec(scope)} >Save</Button>
```

which on Click will call this function:

```html
const exec = async (type: string) => {
    x = 'www';
    await dispatch(exampleRoute());
  };
```

and I have this useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const listenForResponse = async ({ success, message, data }: { success: any, message: any, data: any }) => {
      console.log(x);
    };

    if (socket) {
      socket.removeAllListeners(
        'response',
      );

      socket.on(
        'response',
        listenForResponse
      );
    }
  }, [socketClientId, socket]);
```

I have simplified the function for a better understanding. The problem is that my X variable is being printed in the console as EMPTY, even though it is changed to 'www' in my onClick function. The useEffect is linked to the Sockets which return a response from the API. When the call is complete and the Sockets receive a message, they execute the listenForResponse.

However, the listenForResponse function should not be called until I do the dispatch.

What am I doing wrong?

LE: I have my an input like this:

```js
          <Input type='text' placeholder={'Last Name'} onChange={(e:any) => {setLastName(e.target.value)}}/>
```

It seems that if I do NOT change anything in this, it will work. Also, if I remove the onChange it works, but I don't have the value in the Input set anywhere then..

Comment: have you tried exec function without async?

Comment: it will not work since the dispatch has an await. My bad, will update the question now

Answer (score 0):

Effects run when the component is first rendered and then, again, every time it is re-rendered with a change in the dependency array.

It **has** to run before the click event fires. You won't have anything to click on to trigger the click event before it is rendered.

If you don't want it to do anything until the click event has been fired at least one then your effect function should **test the value of `x` and, if it is the default value, `return` before doing anything**.